# Get an Image from CameraPreview

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

Is there a way I can get an image from a camera preview? The purpose of this would be to overlay an emoji over the face of the camera preview, and I can't overlay the emoji images without first having a Bitmap image as follows:

```
private void processAndSetImage()
{
    mResultsBitmap = OverlayEmoji.detectFacesandOverlayEmoji(this, mResultsBitmap);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mResultsBitmap);
}
```

Is there a way that `mImageView` could have the value of a camera preview? Any links to other SO posts, or articles (in java) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get an image from a camera preview?

No.

First, there are thousands of Android device models. These devices will have dozens, if not hundreds, of "android native camera" apps, as many device manufacturers frequently ship a customized camera app.

Second, there is no requirement that all camera apps have an identical user interface. The size and position of the camera preview can vary. Not only will they vary between apps, but even the same app might vary the size and position of the camera preview between versions of that app, as apps can and do get updated.

Third , you have no good way of determining when any of these camera apps happens to be in the foreground.