# Apply filter over image CameraPreview image feed

Tags: java, android, camera

Related somewhat to:

[Overlay image on cameraPreview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454312/overlay-image-on-camerapreview)

and

[Get an Image from CameraPreview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334054/get-an-image-from-camerapreview)

Is there a more "seamless" way of hooking an image from a CameraPreview applying and applying a set of transforms over it before displaying onto the actual view?

At the moment I have a handler that saves the pictures to a file:

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mPreview);

// Add a listener to the Capture button
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get an image from the camera
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        }
);

private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
};
```

Is there a way (besides using a loop with a condition and a wait time) to hook the camera feed?

Comment: Your question is still not cleat. Your code snippet does not help to understand it: it shows how you capture a picture to file, but has nothing about CameraPreview, and applies no filters.

Comment: Yes, the snippet is from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera . I've managed to apply filters using opengl

Comment: good, so you can close this question now?

Comment: Already found an answer/community suggestion

Comment: Not enough rep :( (I can vote to close but not close).

Comment: You can add the answer you found and accept it!